# radioGroupButtons in a multi row and multi column layout

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a radioGroupButtons with 5 options. Until now it is displayed in vertical with justified = TRUE, but I want to modify the appearance having the 5 buttons divided into 3 rows (first row with 2 options, second row with one centered option and last row with 2 options).

This is what I did until now.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    column(
      7,offset = 1,
          radioGroupButtons(
            "sel_inputdata_type", "Choose one :",
            
            choiceValues = list("lipidsearch", "liquid", "excel", "sumexp", "mw"),
            
            choiceNames = list(
              paste(tags$img(src = "www/lipidsearch_icon.png", height = "27px", width = "27px"), HTML("<b style=font-size:25px>&nbsp;Lipid Search</b>")),
              paste(tags$img(src = "www/liquid_icon.png", height = "29px", width = "29px"), HTML("<b style=font-size:25px>&nbsp;LIQUID</b>")),
              paste(tags$img(src = "www/excel_icon.png", height = "23px", width = "23px"), HTML("<b style=font-size:25px>&nbsp;Excel files</b>")),
              paste(icon("database",  style='font-size:16px;'), HTML("<b style=font-size:25px>&nbsp;Summarized Experiment</b>")),
              paste(tags$img(src = "www/mw_icon.png", height = "27px", width = "27px"), HTML("<b style=font-size:25px>&nbsp;Metabolomics Workbench</b>"))
            ),
            direction = "horizontal",individual=T, status = "primary",size = "lg"
          ))
  )


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this , but here's some CSS to do something pretty close to what you want:

```
div.btn-group:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(2) {
  width: 49%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(3) {
  width: 75%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(4) {
  width: 50%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(3) > button:nth-child(1) {
  margin: ;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}


.active {
  width: 100%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(4) > button:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(5) {
  width: 49%;
}


div.btn-group:nth-child(5) > button:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is not a very flexible solution. If you add more buttons, you'll have to change the CSS all over again.

You can add CSS to shiny in a variety of ways: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Here's what it looks like (the icons didn't load for me) :
[image: buttons alligned]

Comment: Wow a lot of CSS! But unfortunately, there are still two problems. If I click on another button rather than "Lipid Search", that button becomes smaller. And next, it seems that this code is pretty general because it affects many other parts of my shiny app. Is it possible to make it work based on the id of the button?